# React Antd table filterable column and editing a cell

Tags: reactjs, antd

I try to implement a table that has a filterable column and editable cell using Antd table component. So far I have achieved to filter columns but editing behaviour is buggy. It works fine if I edit only one cell one but if I try to edit the second cell first cell gets back to it's previous value.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/blue-bush-3r7m4s?file=%2Fapp%2Fpage.tsx%3A2%2C8)

So far I've tried to add a key attribute to the EditableCell component but it doesn't work either.

```
  return (
    <td {...restProps} key={record?.key}>
      {childNode}
    </td>
  );
```

Edit: I modified handleSave function like this and now works.

```
const handleSave = (row: DataType) => {
setDataSource((prevDataSource) => {
  const newData = [...prevDataSource];
  const index = newData.findIndex((item) => row.key === item.key);
  const updatedRow = { ...newData[index], ...row };
  newData.splice(index, 1, updatedRow);
  return newData;
});
```